# How to implement adjarcent screens in Android?

Tags: android, user-interface

I would like to implement adjarcent screens in Android, so that they can be navigated by swyping to the right and left.

What would be the best way to do so?

[image]

Comment: try using `Fragments` with `FragmentActivity`. Maybe my old answer might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17318468/1276374

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ViewPager
[View Pager](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html)

Answer (score 1):

horizontalscroll view or view pager, take a look at this
http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html